# Trouble with tornado/ asyncio using websocket

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, tornado, python-asyncio

I'm converting my application from Python 2 to Python 3. Briefly, my app works in Python (server) and in Javascript (client), which connect through a websocket, which I get using tornado. At Python, I have multiple threads. I'm not using Python3's asyncio methods anywhere.

However, when converting my app from Python 2.7 (it works perfectly in Python2) to Python 3.7, I'm having problems with tornado/ asyncio.

First, I was getting the error: `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-26'`.

After some googling, I found a recomendation to mitigate this:

```
import tornado.platform.asyncio
import asyncio
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(tornado.platform.asyncio.AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy())
```

This appears to solve that error. However, now I am getting the following warning + error:

```
2019-08-24 13:27:25,455 asyncio      DEBUG    Using selector: SelectSelector
2019-08-24 13:28:25,455 asyncio      ERROR    Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<WebSocketProtocol13.write_message.<locals>.wrapper() running at C:\Users\DLA\PycharmProjects\myPmese\Python3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py:1102>>
```

Any clues on what's happening? Unfortunately I cannot find what exact part of my Python code is causing this.

Many thanks! Any help would be appreciated :)

You can find bellow the architecture of my Python websocket using tornado:

```
import tornado.platform.asyncio
import asyncio
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(tornado.platform.asyncio.AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy())
application = tornado.web.Application([(r'/myPmese/websocket', WSocketHandler)])
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(8295)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

class WSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def initialize(self):
        print('initialize') # here I initialise handlers

    def open(self):
        start_server_code()  # triggers the code from the server.

    def __call__(self, *args):
        clientCommand = self.getClientCommand()
        self.resetClientCommand()
        self.send(clientCommand , *args)

    def send(self, var_func, *args):
        try:
            self.write_message(json.dumps(self.getClientCommand()))
        except Exception as e:
            print(traceback.format_exc())

    def on_message(self, message):
        if message != '':
            try:
                eval(self.executeCommand(message))
            except Exception as e:
                print(traceback.format_exc())
                self.send('createErrorMessage', str(e))

    def on_close(self):
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```